# how does one loop a video using ffmpeg on android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I'm using hiteshsondhi88's  "FFmpeg Android Java" library and it works fine for scaling, trans-coding, and overlaying. However, when I try to loop a video I just get the same un-looped video on my output.

My code:

```
String internalPath = getFilesDir().getPath(); //get internal directory
String command = "-y -f concat -i "+internalPath+"/myList.txt -c copy "+internalPath+"/final.mp4";
ffmpeg.execute(command, ffmpegResponseHandler);
```

The text in "myList.txt" is generated programmatically but it looks like this:

```
file 'final_unlooped.mp4' file 'final_unlooped.mp4' file 'final_unlooped.mp4' file 'final_unlooped.mp4' file 'final_unlooped.mp4'
```

Finally, the log:

```
ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Oct  7 2014 15:11:41 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/i686-linux-android- --arch=x86 --cpu=i686 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/x86 --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -march=i686' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
Input #0, concat, from '/data/data/com.testApp/files/myList.txt':
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 744 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x640, 744 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
Output #0, mp4, to '/data/data/com.testApp/files/final.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x640, q=2-31, 744 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  115 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     420kB time=00:00:04.48 bitrate= 768.1kbits/s
video:418kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.509634%
```

The OnSuccess() method in the response handler launches indicating that the execution was successful but the output is still unlooped.

This command works fine on Windows but for some reason it wont work on Android. any ideas of what it could be, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the problem.

Turns out that I had to add an extra line "/n" after each file name in "myList.txt" so that it look like this:

```
file 'final_unlooped.mp4'
file 'final_unlooped.mp4'
file 'final_unlooped.mp4'
...
```

Instead of this:

```
file 'final_unlooped.mp4' file 'final_unlooped.mp4' file 'final_unlooped.mp4' ...
```

I hope that someone finds this useful.